# TCPDF - generating a PDF within browser but also playing an audio

Tags: audio, tcpdf

I'm writing in raw PHP on Linux using the tcpdf library.
The core question is that while creating a PDF with tcpdf I'd also like to kick off an audio file for the user...but tcpdf considers that `TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file` so I'm looking for a way to play an audio file at PDF generation without tcpdf considering that 'interfering output'.

I can successfully generate my wanted PDF within my browser using the tcpdf library and calls.  But I would also like to play an audio when this happens - that might say "This is your generated PDF.   You can print it now...etc"

So I'm wanting to put the HTML audio syntax within my php script.
However if I try to include an audio clause before the tcpdf->output, tcpdf will play the audio but say that output has happened before the tcpdf output and will not generate the PDF image.  Flow stops after the tcpdf->output command - it successfully generates the PDF but it does not return for additional lines so I can't place the audio line after the output call.

So I guess I'm looking for a "hidden" audio although I've tried hidden attributes within the HTML audio syntax but still tcpdf flags it as "output has happened".  Thank you.

Comment: Even apart from the unfinished sentence at the end, this question feels like it's missing rather crucial information: What language / framework are you programming in? What do you mean by "flow stops after..."? What actual code have you tried? Please take a look at the [help] and then [edit] your question to include some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, you can do that simply by

- generate the PDF into file (not to the client directly -- `'F'` switch).
- output your audio file to the client and let it platy
- output a link/Javascript redirection to the generated PDF file.

Because you didn't provide any code in your question I do not provide any either, but I believe it is already understandable.

Comment: Thank you Jakuje.  I will give that a try.  The redirection afterwards is key.  Thanks!